# Selected state is not retaining new selected option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Browser: Opera

So, the issue I'm having, is that when a selection with onChange() is made, the selected option will immediately display (go back) to its previous selected option state.

So, and using the following code:

```js
cont options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

class funcName extends React.Component {

render() {

return (

logChange = (val) => { 
    console.log("Selected: " + val);
}

<Select
    name="form-field-name"
    value="one"
    options={options}
    onChange={logChange}
/>
);
}
}
```

attempting to select option 'Two' is never retained. Immediately the selection is made it goes back to select option 'One' and the displayed value of (val) is always 'One'. If I comment out the onChange line, then the select box functions as expected.

What is the issue here?

Comment: There is a typo in your options declaration. Also, shouldn't you be passing options in as props? Is this the full program?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but it looks like you are using a custom component named "Select".  I'd check the documentation for that.  If it works like most things in React, you'll need to update the value prop that you send to the component to have it change visually.  It is sending you the value selected by the user via the callback, but storing that value and updating the component props is on you.  Furthermore, I'd wager removing the onChange causes this component to revert to an uncontrolled mode.  Maybe start by using a built-in "select" and check out Alex's answer to that end.

Comment: @RobLynch The following plunker displays the issue I mentioned above: https://plnkr.co/edit/HTmtER9AMNcPoWhXV707?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root problem is that you don't actually have a component doing anything in your code, so the Select just renders with the static props you set in the beginning.

As Alex says, you need to update the `value` prop that you are sending to the Select component in order for it to update visually.  At a very basic level you do this by calling setState on a parent component, which you have not created in your example, and pass that value to the child Select component.

```
<Select
  name="form-field-name"
  value={this.state.selection.value}
  options={options}
  onChange={this.changeSelection}
/>
```

I have updated your code here for a complete working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/TlUe2eJd3OSxGkdHIKJP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

By specifying the `value` field you reassign the value each time the render function is invoked. Use `defaultValue` instead.

LE: Might be worth reading a bit about controlled vs uncontrolled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html